# C# - Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `int[][]' - CodeFights

Tags: c#

When attempting to use the following bit of code to answer a question Box Blur on the website CodeFights.com, I receive the following message which has me stumped:

```
file.cs on line 2: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `int[][]'
```

I'm confident that this is something simple that I'm missing but, my searching for an answer to this has not returned any success.

Any ideas as to what simple mistake I am committing?

```
int[][] boxBlur(int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrix.Length-2][matrix[0].Length-2];
    for (int i =1; i < matrix.Length-1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < matrix[0].Length-1; j++) 
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(int k=i-1; k<=i+1; k++) 
            {
                for(int m=j-1;m<=j+1;m++) 
                {
                    sum+=matrix[k][m];
                }               
            }
            result[i-1][j-1]=sum/9;
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The error you are getting is not from the code you have posted. Is there more code that you did not post?

Comment: I get a different compiler error than you do for this code.

Comment: LINQpad gives me `Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'` for the above code (the fix for that error is shown in @Bibop's answer). Are you sure you've shown the proper code? Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong call array. Try this(or something like):

```
int[][] result = new int[matrix.Length - 2][];
for(int i=0; i< matrix.Length - 2; i++)
{
    result[i] = new int[matrix[0].Length - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int[][] is an array of arrays. You can't initialize the size of the arrays within it when you're initializing it.
If you want a two-dimensional array, use int[,].